# Problem to do an arrays exercise. Beginner inside

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm learning Javascript, and I have a problem with arrays in `Javascript`, and I have to do a `class` called **TV Show** with title, thematicand and actors (actors with array) Then, I have to do a function to grab a specific actor and classify it as "favorite" randomly.

Once done, I get an "empty" array.

This is my code.

```
class TVShow {
    constructor (title, thematic, principalActors){
        var arrayActors = new Array();
        this.title=title;
        this.thematic=thematic;
        principalActors=[];
    
        this.generateFavActor = function(){
            var long = principalActors.lenght;
            let calc = Math.floor(Math.random()*(long));
            arrayActors = principalActors[calc];
        }
        console.log(arrayActors);
    }
}
var show01= new TVShow("The Revolution", "Accion",["Hello","Hello2"]);
show01.generateFavActor();

var show02 = new TVShow("Peaky Blinders", "Drama",["Hello","Hello2", "Hello3"] );
show02.generateFavActor();

var show03 = new TVShow ("Stranger Things", "Accion", ["Hello","Hello2", "Hello3", "Hello4"]); 
show03.generateFavActor();
```

Thanks!!

Comment: `principalActors.lenght` should `principalActors.length`.

Comment: You also set `principalActors` to an empty array inside your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
class TVShow {
    constructor (title, thematic, principalActors){        
        this.title=title;
        this.thematic=thematic;
        this.arrayActors = principalActors;       
    
        this.generateFavActor = function(){
            var size = principalActors.length;
            let calc = Math.floor(Math.random()*(size));
            return principalActors[calc];
        }        
        this.favoriteActor = this.generateFavActor();
    }
}

var show01 = new TVShow("The Revolution", "Accion",["Hello","Hello2"]);
var fav01 = show01.favoriteActor;

var show02 = new TVShow("Peaky Blinders", "Drama",["Hello","Hello2", "Hello3"] );
var fav02 = show02.favoriteActor;

var show03 = new TVShow ("Stranger Things", "Accion", ["Hello","Hello2", "Hello3", "Hello4"]); 
var fav03 = show03.favoriteActor;

console.log(fav01);
console.log(fav02);
console.log(fav03);
```

Answer (score 2):

that ? ( [using Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) )

```js
class TVShow
  {
  constructor (title, thematic, principalActors)
    {
    this.title    = title
    this.thematic = thematic
    this.actors   = [...principalActors]
    }
  generateFavActor()
    {
    console.log( this.actors[ Math.floor(Math.random()*this.actors.length ) ])
    }
  }
var show01 = new TVShow('The Revolution',  'Accion', ['Hello','Hello2'])
  , show02 = new TVShow('Peaky Blinders',  'Drama',  ['Hello','Hello2', 'Hello3'] )
  , show03 = new TVShow('Stranger Things', 'Accion', ['Hello','Hello2', 'Hello3', 'Hello4'])
  ;
show01.generateFavActor()
show02.generateFavActor()
show03.generateFavActor()
```

Comment: Yes, thank you!!! You have a very nice code, I have a lot to learn.

Comment: @dan-ss93 thank you, I can only encourage you to follow this path, (PS I use WhiteSmith style, with some personal arrangements)

Answer (score 1):

first correct the `principalActors.length` not `principalActors.lenght`
Second don't set `principalActors` as an empty array 
 Next  Just put `console.log` inside the function... 
 it will give you the right answer...right now it is showing the value which is just assigned to an empty array `var arrayActors = new Array()`
 Hope it will be HelpFul :-)
 and I think `arrayActors` don'nt need to be an an array

```
class TVShow {
    constructor (title, thematic, principalActors){
        var arrayActors = new Array();
        this.title=title;
        this.thematic=thematic;
        
    
        this.generateFavActor = function(){
            var long = principalActors.length;
            let calc = Math.floor(Math.random()*(long));
           arrayActors = principalActors[calc];
           console.log(arrayActors);
        }
        
    }
}
var show01= new TVShow("The Revolution", "Accion",["Hello","Hello2"]);
show01.generateFavActor();

var show02 = new TVShow("Peaky Blinders", "Drama",["Hello","Hello2", "Hello3"] );
show02.generateFavActor();

var show03 = new TVShow ("Stranger Things", "Accion", ["Hello","Hello2", "Hello3", "Hello4"]); 
show03.generateFavActor();
```